# LineChart of google.charts, choose numeric format on axes without changing locale

Tags: google-visualization

I program a web application in which users may choose their language and number format independently of each other, and I would like to use the LineChart from google.charts to show a graph with dates on one axis and numbers on the other axis. Now I can set a language to "en" and set the format on the haxis to display dates in an English format, as "Nov 12". But how do I format the numbers on the vaxis to use '.' as thousand separator, i.e. display 1000 as "1.000" rather than "1,000"? (The formatter appears to only affect the tooltips).

Complete example:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], language: 'en'});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Date', 'Numeric data'],
              [new Date(2012, 10, 12), 1000],
              [new Date(2012, 10, 13), 1200],
              [new Date(2012, 10, 14), 1100],
              [new Date(2012, 10, 15), 1300]
            ]);
            var options = {
              hAxis: {
                  format: "MMM dd"
              },
              vAxis: {
              }
            };
            var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ decimalSymbol: ',', groupingSymbol: '.' });
            formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to second column
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('mychart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mychart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could provide custom formatted vaxis labels

build an array of the ticks to be displayed

use object notation to provide a formatted value

```
var vTicks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  vTicks.push({
    v: data.getValue(i, 1),
    f: data.getFormattedValue(i, 1),
  });
}
```

-- or --

```
var vTicks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  vTicks.push({
    v: data.getValue(i, 1),
    f: formatter.formatValue(data.getValue(i, 1))
  });
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], language: 'en'});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Numeric data'],
    [new Date(2012, 10, 12), 1000],
    [new Date(2012, 10, 13), 1200],
    [new Date(2012, 10, 14), 1100],
    [new Date(2012, 10, 15), 1300]
  ]);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ decimalSymbol: ',', groupingSymbol: '.' });
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  // build custom ticks, use object notation to for formatted values
  var vTicks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    vTicks.push({
      v: data.getValue(i, 1),
      f: data.getFormattedValue(i, 1),
    });
  }

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
        format: "MMM dd"
    },
    vAxis: {
      ticks: vTicks
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('mychart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="mychart"></div>
```

**EDIT**

rather than use the exact values from the data,
it may make sense to provide your own,
based on the *range* of values

DataTable has a method for `getColumnRange` which returns an object with properties for min and max

use those values to build the `ticks`, see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], language: 'en'});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Numeric data'],
    [new Date(2012, 10, 12), 1050],
    [new Date(2012, 10, 13), 1250],
    [new Date(2012, 10, 14), 1150],
    [new Date(2012, 10, 15), 1350]
  ]);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ decimalSymbol: ',', groupingSymbol: '.' });
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  // get range for y axis
  var colRange = data.getColumnRange(1);
  var tickMin = Math.floor(colRange.min/100)*100;  // round down to nearest 100
  var tickMax = Math.ceil(colRange.max/100)*100;  // round up to nearest 100

  // build custom ticks
  var vTicks = [];
  for (var i = tickMin; i <= tickMax + 100; i=i+100) {
    vTicks.push({
      v: i,
      f: formatter.formatValue(i),
    });
  }

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      format: "MMM dd"
    },
    vAxis: {
      ticks: vTicks
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('mychart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="mychart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, better than anything I have come up with so far. My problem, however, is that you take over the control of which numbers should be displayed on the vAxis. The difference can be seen by changing the data, e.g. by replacing 1200 by 1250. Then my code continues to have 1000 1100 1200 1300 displayed on the vAxis, while your code changes to having 1000 1100 1250 1300. Is there a way to leave it with the LineChart to find appropriate numbers, and at the same time take over control of their format?

Comment: yes, the easiest would be to use a format string, but I can't seem to get one to work with period as grouping symbol -- see __EDIT__ to above answer -- uses `getColumnRange` to build `ticks`, rather than actual data values

Comment: Yes, that works if I know approximately which range of values to expect (but not very well for values e.g. between 7 and 8). Google is probably better at choosing appropriate ticks based on the actual data, and therefore I was hoping to be able to keep their algorithm. In this case I guess I have two possibilities. Either extend their code with a callback function that allows me to format the ticks as I want, or dig out the ticks algorithm from their code and apply it to build custom formatted ticks like you have done.